# trigger IO : not able to import the existing project

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I am just started with the trigger IO . I have downloaded the toolkit on my mac machine . I can create new project from UI .But when I am importing the existing project it is giving me the error : `Failed to import app: Already have an app imported from /foler path` . My folder containing src folder also valid config file . can anybody help me ?